# I want to apply my MongoDB query to Javascript(select specific column)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, select, nosql, nestjs

Hi I'm working with my MongoDB and NestJS.

I was testing by query below. And it was what I expected

[image: query testing]

I only want to get '_id'. So I tested my code too.

```
// // This is what I use(including comments)
// const { MongoClient, ObjectID } = require('mongodb');

// const url = 'mongodb+srv://alex:~ something';
// console.log(url);
// const client = new MongoClient(url);

// // Database Name
// const dbName = 'testDB';

export async function getCreaterPubGameId(authorID: string) {
  await client.connect();
  console.log('Connected successfully to server : update, find or insertData');
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  const collection = db.collection('games');

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    collection.find({ authorID }, { type: '_id' }).toArray((err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log('getAlldata : ', doc);
        resolve(doc);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

After I use this function, I got all the data from MongoDB.

[image: NestJS(Node) Result]

As you see, I used the same syntax. But I got all the data.
Is there anybody who has a good idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export async function getCreaterPubGameId(authorID: string) {
  await client.connect();
  console.log('Connected successfully to server : update, find or insertData');
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  const collection = db.collection('games');

// I have to use 'projection'
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    collection.find({ authorID }, { projection: { _id: true }).toArray((err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log('getAlldata : ', doc);
        resolve(doc);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Link : https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#find

Answer (score 1):

You need to use projection when using MongoDb Node.js client.

```
export async function getCreaterPubGameId(authorID: string) {
  await client.connect();
  console.log('Connected successfully to server : update, find or insertData');
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  const collection = db.collection('games');

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    collection.find({ authorID }, { "type": 1}).toArray((err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log('getAlldata : ', doc);
        resolve(doc);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

When you pass `1` to any field, it will be added to the prjection field and will only show those schema field. By default `_id` will be included if you want to not include it pass `_id: 0`.